# Kotlin RPC client

Tags: kotlin, jvm, rpc

Is there an RPC client/library for Kotlin/JVM? I know about gRPC, but is there another one?

I am trying to write an API in Kotlin for Microsoft's AirSim simulator and the python API they provide is using the msgpack-rpc library so  I thought I should do something similar.

Comment: Try gRPC: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/kotlin/quickstart/

Comment: I'm asking about other than gRPC as stated in the post